# How do you check whether a cell contains a number and then condtionally run another function based off of that? I tried multiple solutions none worked

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How would you do something like checking if the cell has a number and then running a function conditionally?

I tried this =IF(B5 ISNUMBER(MINUS(B4,B5))) but I got formula parse error, why? What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
=if(isnumber(B5),B4-B5,)
```